# How to squeeze the value inside a textbox to a little bit(say 5px) right

Tags: css, html

I have tried to use :

```
padding-left : 5px
```

inside the input(which is a text box) style. But it doesn't work.

There must be a way to do it, because I can see the effect all over the world but not on my wb page.

Thanks.

Comment: post the code that's not working. padding left should work

Comment: Padding works.. http://jsfiddle.net/A8X7u/

Comment: Check to see if any other style sheets are overriding your 5px padding. Padding-left should work.

Comment: @Ani  yes, it works, I lost my mind for AN HOUR!!! what a shame >_<;

Comment: @JoshC  yes it works mate. I lost my mind for 1 hour for no reasons....

Comment: @Randy  thx Randy. I wrote it in a wrong way.  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my fault.

I wrongly wrote it like this:

```
  <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { placeholder = "Name", padding_left = " 5px;" })</p>
```

But it should be like this way.

```
  <p>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { placeholder = "Name", style = "padding-left: 5px;" })</p>
```

Thank you all for your timely replies.  :)